# force user to re-login after 4 hours - how?

Tags: login

Does anyone know of a way to force a logged in user to re-login after say 4 hours?  or at a particular time to day?

For example, if they logged in at 9am, can we force them to re-login at 1pm?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to change the authentication cookie expiry time.

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'wase_85171_expiry',10,3);

function wase_85171_expiry($expiry, $user_id, $remember) {
  return 14400; // or calculate the time remaining till the time you want it to expire
}
```

People can extend the cookie expiry in the browser, but I don't believe anyone will bother

Comment: where do I add this code?

Comment: at your themes functions.php file

Answer (score 1):

You can write *javascript* which will start on `wp_login` action, count `4x60x60` seconds and redirect user to URL generated by `wp_logout_url()`.

**Update**: it's a good idea to force logout only after N minutes the user is idle. You can get the idea and link to source code in [jQuery idleTimer plugin](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/) article by Paul Irish. Unfortunately, demo does not work.

Comment: this is a good idea, complementary to what J.Chin Asked for. But I'm pretty sure it would be safer on the server side (in PHP then). Ben Then JS could still be used in order to hide still opened page

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically logout a user in Wordpress by calling the wp_logout() function.
To apply this to your 4 hour rule, consider the following code:

```
function user_update_login($login) {
    // function fires when a user logs in

    global $user_ID;
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);

    // save the current time when the user logged in
    update_usermeta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action('wp_login','user_update_login');

function check_time_limit() {
    // populate the user objects
    get_currentuserinfo();
    global $user_ID;

    // only run if the user is logged in
    if($user_ID) {
        // get the last login time
        $last_login = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'last_login', TRUE);

        // if the current time is greater than the last login
        // + 14400 seconds (4 hours) the user will be logged out
        if(time() > ($last_login + 14400)) {
            wp_logout();
        }
    }
}
check_time_limit();
```

Putting this code in your functions.php file will log ALL users out after 4 hours.
You could also move the call to check_time_limit() anywhere within your theme if you only want this rule to apply to specific pages etc.

Comment: no because it only fires if $user_ID is set, i.e the user has to be logged in again before the check will run and thereby the last_login meta value will be updated first. works fine for me.

Comment: yes, after another 4 hours, thats the whole point.

Comment: lol, my mistake, going to delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a plugin named [WP Login Timeout Settings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-login-timeout-settings/screenshots/). you can set timeout for the loggedin user to re-login.